# Angular 4 Binding function in template file

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to check some condition in angular. So I use the following method.

```
<span> {{checkValue("test")}} </span>
```

Then My component like

```js
checkValue(val){
 if ("test" == val){
    return "value is true"
  }
}
```

in this case the function call continuously. 
Is this correct method or suggest me any other idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Binding a variable to a template means that at every lifecycle step, Angular will check this variable. In the case of a function, it will call it. 

You can't stop that (for all I know), and you should not, otherwise Angular will stop checking for changes on your variables.

Comment: in my app, it can't stop. so app got to crash.

Comment: I see why : you're assigning a value to your variable, so it triggers a new change detection. I don't see the point of what you're doing, you could simply display `<span>name</span>`.

Comment: After your edit, you can simply use `{{ "test" === "test" ? 'Value is true' : '' }}`, That's basically what your function does, but in one line.

Answer (score 0):

As **@trichetriche** mentioned

> Binding a variable to a template means that at every lifecycle step,
>   Angular will check this variable. In the case of a function, it will
>   call it. You can't stop that (for all I know), and you should not,
>   otherwise Angular will stop checking for changes on your variables.

You should avoid  doing this. I believe you should try find the best solution before doing this.

In your case you can check this in html itself. So it will return `true` or `false`.

Try this

```
<span *ngIf="val =="test""> value is true </span>
```

Comment: Neither does it resolves the issue, nor does it fulfill the OP's requirement to display "name".

Comment: (And vulturing over my explanations isn't something I like that much)

Comment: Still not okay. `val` is a parameter of his function, so you're comparing `undefined` to "test".

Comment: oohhh, Seems like OP has edited the question. My bad

Answer (score 0):

The code in you example is perfectly valid, function will be triggered at every change detection pass, there must be something else that triggers change detection i.e. `setInterval`, http calls and so on.

Comment: The question has been edited, and this should be a comment.

Comment: Actual error is <li [ngClass]="{active: activeRoute('starter')}">name</li> Component like.. activeRoute(routename: string): boolean{console.log("navigator"); return this.router.url.indexOf(routename) > -1; }

Comment: My question is is this correct way or give any other idea?

Comment: Like I said code is correct, without error description it impossible to suggest anything.